# jQuery animation fails randomly

Tags: jquery

I tried to implement jQuery animation in my site, but randomly after seconds, minutes or hours, the animation throws an error: "Invalid property value" Line 154 Char 4889 jquery-ui-1.7.2-custom.js.

Here is my code:

```
            $(idTimer).animate({backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#ffffff'}, 1000);
            $(idPrice).animate({backgroundColor: '#aa0000', color: '#ffffff'}, 1000);
            
            $(idTimer).animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff', color: '#f67802'}, 1000);
            $(idPrice).animate({backgroundColor: '#ffffff', color: '#000000'}, 1000);
```

Of course the IDs are correctly set. When the animation hangs up, no animation will be done anymore for this ID, so it's very mysterious.

Here is the failing code, beginning char 4889:

```
h.elem.style[f]="rgb("+[Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((h.pos*(h.end[0]-h.start[0]))+h.start[0],10),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((h.pos*(h.end[1]-h.start[1]))+h.start[1],10),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((h.pos*(h.end[2]-h.start[2]))+h.start[2],10),255),0)].join(",")+")"}});
```

Comment: I have the same problem with color animations in jQuery - seemingly at random a color animation will stop. Hopefully someone has an answer!

Comment: Can you post Line 154 Char 4889 in your file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this

```
$(idTimer).animate({'backgroundColor': '#aa0000', 'color': '#ffffff'}, 1000);
```